# What is the L in numpy.shape and 32 in numpy.type of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying the functions of numpy arrays and below is the code:

```
import numpy as np

Z =np.array( 
    [[0,4,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0],
     [0,1,0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0]])
print Z
print Z.dtype
print Z.shape
```

Which gave:

```
[[0 4 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
int32
(6L, 6L)
```

It is an integer array with 6 rows and 6 columns. But what is the 32 from numpy.type and the L in numpy.shape?

Answer (score 22):

The 32 in the [array type](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) refers to 32-bit width of the underlying machine integer that stores the array. This means that an array with, say, 1 million elements, will take up at least 4 million bytes (32 million bits) of memory.

On the other hand, the suffix `L` returned by the `shape` property has nothing to do with the data you can put in your arrays and you should not be concerned with it. If you are interested in the techical details, `L` denotes the `long` Python type. That type was used by Python 2 to represent integers of unbounded width, and is not to be confused with the C type of the same name. It doesn't make much sense to represent a small integer such as the number 6 as Python `long`, but some code did it anyway for consistency with cases when the same API could return a larger integer. For example, the Python 2 `os.stat` always returned byte sizes in long integers, even if they would fit the regular `int` type, in order to maintain type invariance of its return value.

The `L` suffix and the distinction between `long` and `int` is not present in Python 3.

Comment: I have seen there are also 64bit type and probably others (maybe 128bit) as well. What are the advantages of having a larger bit, since you can already store in a 32bit? And can you combine 2 arrays with different bits? Regarding long from L, when you mean unbounded width, does it mean the integer can be of infinite significant figures within a cell?

Comment: @user3211991 Bit size is always a tradeoff: wider types provide a larger range of representable numbers at the expense of increased memory usage. For example, a 32-bit integer can hold numbers between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, while a 64-bit integer can hold numbers between -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, while requiring double amount of memory.

Comment: @user3211991 the "L" refers to numbers returned by the `shape` property and has nothing to do with numbers stored in the cells. Unbounded width refers to integers of arbitrary size, the numeric equivalent of how computers store strings of arbitrary size.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of said "L"?

Comment: @Zap Use `print "%d" % your_long_value`. Or switch to Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

On my machine it gives `(6, 6)`, the `L` on you machines marks it as *long integer*.

i.e.

```
In [133]: type(123L) is long
Out[133]: True
```