# Numpy.shape has a suffix: optimal way to get rid of it

Tags: python, numpy

Having read [What is the L in numpy.shape and 32 in numpy.type of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284790/what-is-the-l-in-numpy-shape-and-32-in-numpy-type-of-an-array) I know *why* the "L" suffix is there. But I want to do some operations that involve knowing the size of my dataset.

Clearly I can do some simple string processing to get rid of the suffix, but I don't want to assume it's always there (it wasn't last time I ran the code on a different machine).

So what's the pythonic way to deal with this?  Is there something I should be using instead of `shape()`?  Is there a simple "cast the numeric part to integer and throw away the rest" function I should use on the output? Is there some way of telling `shape()` I don't want the suffix?

Bonus question: When was this introduced/why would it appear on one system and not another (both python 2.7, numpy version of the old system unknown)?  There's no mention of it in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) so no history to help me know whether I can assume that new systems will have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `L` is an artefact of displaying the value, indicating that the value is being stored as a `long`, rather than as an `int`: it is not actually *part* of the value.  Therefore, you can just ignore it.

```
>>> num = 123L # create a long for testing
>>> num
123L
>>> num + 1    # simple operations
124L
>>> len(range(num)) # function calls
123
>>> math.sqrt(num) # math module calls also work, most of the time.
11.090536506409418
```

If you *must* get rid of it, you can use `int()`:

```
>>> int(num) # convert to int
123
```

The only time it can be a problem is if you have an extremely large value:

```
>>> num = 2147483648
>>> num
2147483648L
>>> range(num)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: range() result has too many items
```

Although if you're using `range` with arguments that large, you are probably being unpythonic somewhere along the line.

Comment: Well *something* was giving me a TypeError on the line where I tried to subtract from it - but when I reinstated the subtraction it wasn't.  And I didn't know `int` could do that, so thank you twice over.